# Block duplicate orders in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've been looking a lot for a solution to avoid accidental duplicate Woocommerce orders.
I wrote a php code that basically solves the problem.
I would need a little help so that if all the items in the cart are the same, only then should it be considered a duplicate order.

The $seconds variable is the timespan to check time between orders.

All help is appreciated.

```
/**
* Block duplicate orders in Woocommerce
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_process_transient', 10, 1 );
function thankyou_process_transient( $order_id='' ) {
    $seconds = 60; //The transient's expiry duration in seconds
    $product_ids = array();
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) && !empty($order_id) ) {
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();
        if ( !empty($customer_email) ) {
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                array_push($product_ids,  $item->get_variation_id() != 0 ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item->get_product_id() ) ;
            }
        }
        if (function_exists('wc_customer_bought_product_last_n_seconds') ) {
            wc_customer_bought_product_last_n_seconds( $customer_email, $product_ids, $seconds );
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_process','before_checkout_process_transient');
function before_checkout_process_transient() {
    $customer_email = '';
    $product_ids = array();

    if (is_checkout() ) {
        if( isset($_POST['billing_email']) && !empty($_POST['billing_email']) && is_email($_POST['billing_email']) ) {
            $customer_email = $_POST['billing_email'];
        }
        
        if ( !empty($customer_email) ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                $product = $cart_item['data'];
                array_push($product_ids, $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ? $product->variation_id : $product->get_id() ) ;
            }

            if ( function_exists('wc_customer_bought_product_last_n_seconds') && 
            wc_customer_bought_product_last_n_seconds( $customer_email, $product_ids, 0 ) ) {  //User bought these products within n seconds
                WC()->cart->empty_cart( false );
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
* Checks if a user (by email or ID or both) has bought an item.
*
* @param string $customer_email Customer email to check.
* @param array  $product_ids Product IDs to check.
* @param int    $seconds Set the transient's expiry duration in seconds or 0 to get the transient's value
* @return bool
*/
function wc_customer_bought_product_last_n_seconds( $customer_email='', $product_ids, $seconds ) {

    $seconds = absint($seconds);
    if( ! is_array($product_ids) || empty($customer_email) ) { return false; }

    $transient_name = 'wc_customer_bought_product_last_n_seconds_' . md5( $customer_email );
    $bought = false;

    if ( $seconds > 0 ) { //set transient
        sort($product_ids);
        set_transient( $transient_name, $product_ids, $seconds );
    } else { //get transient
        $bought = is_array( get_transient( $transient_name ) ); //true if transient exists
    }

    return $bought;
}
```